# Chatter Comment Feeds - or Hashtags - Reporting

Tags: reporting, chatter, custom-report-type, feedcomment

I have a Case system in place for handling "Salesforce and Other Requests" in our company.  People submit Cases, they get handled and closed.

For both "fairness" purposes (a Case is meant for something that takes "at least 15 minutes" by the definition we've all agreed upon), **a Case is not created when we're doing a quick-and-dirty request** (making a record change that is locked out to most users, checking a log from one of our GotoWebinar processors, etc).  So, we've adopted people **chattering on the record in question** saying "please do whatever".  We then comment back (eventually) **the word "Done"** at the beginning of the final comment (might add extra comments, but always prefixed with the word "Done").

Either *using Hashtags*, or continuing with the simple *prefix-word "Done"* system, we'd like a *report to show all related Comments* (either "starts with 'Done'" or occurrences of a hashtag, perhaps #SFAdminDone as an example).  This way if anyone questions the SF Administration is sitting around doing nothing, we have not only our chatter feed "per user"  (verbose and overkill and not simplified), but better a Report (to accompany Open and Closed Case Reports).

I've checked *(quite thoroughly I believe)* the SF Help site.  Best info was two items, one a post from @Bob_Buzzard, and the other, [vague mention that Feeds and Comments](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006010) are available under the User object specifically.  No help there or the 15-20 other pages I read through.

Help?  Any thoughts?

The alternative is to create and close a Case for every "micro request".  Not appealing - time consuming when it was a simple item that took 1-10 minutes usually.

Comment: Side note:   Ultimately, if there is no solution using hashtags or a report on Comments in Chatter, I'll likely come up with a way to do a "quick Case", a special field that when clicked, only requires 1 or 2 fields to be filled in and perhaps even auto-close the case.   (sigh)   At least then ALL DATA would be in one object.   Hmmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately comes down to the fact that... you simply can't do it without making something in Apex that does it (if it would even do what I need at all).

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YfNMAA0

Promote this idea please.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with Hashtags, you would need to create a new custom Report Type on the HashtagDefinition object.

Setup->Create->Report Types

Then create a new Custom Report Type with the primary object as HashtagDefinition. This will let you pull in some relevant fields for what you want to do, the Hashtag Name and the count of how many times the Hashtag is used.

Alternatively, you can use this SOQL query:

SELECT Id, Name, HashtagCount FROM HashtagDefinition WHERE Name = 'SFAdminDone'

Edit:

Unfortunately, if you want to demonstrate this within certain date ranges, or do trending on it, I do not know that this would be possible as it stores the hashtags aggregated.

Double Edit:

I did find a way to do time-based reporting on this, but unfortunately I do not see a way to do it through creating a custom report type, as the TopicAssignment object is not available (only looked at it briefly though).

But the following SOQL query will find the time when each hashtag is mentioned:

SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM TopicAssignment WHERE Topic.Name = 'SFAdminDone'